# nginx upstream, detect 502 and upstream retries

Tags: http, nginx, proxy

We use nginx in front of our "backend" app as a reverse proxy. Sometimes the HTTP server on our app just closes the connection due to a bug which causes the reverse proxy (nginx or apache) to return 502 to the clients.

To avoid this and make nginx retry the requests, we have configured the same upstream multiple times so nginx retries the request after 502 on the same server like so:

```
upstream mybackend {
    server 10.250.1.5:123 fail_timeout=2s;
    server 10.250.1.5:123 fail_timeout=2s;
    server 10.250.1.5:123 fail_timeout=2s;
...
}
```

and somewhere else:

```
proxy_pass http://mybackend/myurl;
proxy_redirect http://mybackend/myurl /myurl;
```

Is there a way to count/log how many upstream servers nginx tried on each request? 
I need this in order to check if changes in app result in any improvements.

Comment: You should not do it this way for that. You should handle the error using `proxy_intercept_errors` and then use recursive fallback retries. In these retries you can always set print a attempt count to your nginx access log. See this for more details https://serverfault.com/questions/537269/nginx-reverse-proxy-try-upstream-a-then-b-then-a-again.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I will try this, thank you. Can you provide an example with limited logged retries?